# React native shared elements won't work with react navigation 4

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to implement react-navigation-shared-elements with react-navigation v4, but somthing wrong with the way I'm trying.

I have Screen , that contain component ( SectionList) that rendering and other component ( TaskCard ) that contain the wanted shared element.

I've tried to implement this according to the documentation, but it's not working.

Please see the code:

My Router:

```
const HomeStack = createSharedElementStackNavigator({
    HomeScreen,
    TaskDetailsScreen,
    EditTaskScreen,
}, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: headerDefaultOption,
});

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        SplashScreen,
        AuthStack,
        HomeStack,
    }
);
```

HomeScreen that contain the SectionList component:

```
export const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {

   const onTaskPressHandler = (task) => {
        navigation.push(screens.TASK_DETAILS_SCREEN, {task});
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TaskList data={tasks} onTaskPress={onTaskPressHandler} onTaskLongPress={openQuickActionsWithData}/>
        </View>
    );
};
```

TaskList:

```
export const TaskList = ({data, onTaskPress, onTaskLongPress}) => {

    data.sort((a, b) => (a.taskEndDate > b.taskEndDate) ? 1 : ((b.taskEndDate > a.taskEndDate) ? -1 : 0));

    return (
        <SectionList
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            sections={sortedData}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
            renderItem={({item, index}) => {
                return (
                    <TaskCard data={item} index={index} onTaskPress={onTaskPress} onTaskLongPress={onTaskLongPress}/>
                );
            }}
            renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}, section: {data}}) => {
                return (
                    renderTitleIfHasData(data, title)
                );
            }}
        />
    );
};
```

TaskCard with shared element :

```
import {SharedElement} from 'react-native-shared-element';

export const TaskCard = ({data, index, onTaskPress, onTaskLongPress}) => {

    const onPressHandler = data => {
        onTaskPress(data)
    };

    return (
        <Animated.View rkey={index} style={[styles.mainContainer, {transform: [{scale: scaleAnim}]}]}>
        
            <TouchableOpacity
                index={index}
                activeOpacity={layout.activeOpacity}
                style={[styles.taskContainer, {backgroundColor: isFinished ? color.ORANGE : color.GREY,}, renderBorderRadiusPosition()]}
                onPress={() => onPressHandler(data)}
                onLongPress={() => onTaskLongPress(data)}>

                <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
                
                    <SharedElement id={`data.${data.taskCreationDate}.sharedTask`}>
                        <View style={styles.taskImageTypeContainer}>
                            <Image source={getTaskImageByType(data.taskType)} style={styles.typeImageStyle}/>
                        </View>
                    </SharedElement>
                    
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </Animated.View>
    );
};
```

Details screen with same shared element :

```
export const TaskDetailsScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center'}}>
           
                <SharedElement id={`data.${task.taskCreationDate}.sharedTask`}>
                    <View style={styles.taskTypeContainer}>
                        <Image source={getTaskImageByType(task.taskType)} style={styles.taskTypeImage}/>
                    </View>
                </SharedElement>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
};

TaskDetailsScreen.sharedElements = (navigation, otherNavigation, showing) => {
    const task = navigation.getParam('task');
    return [{
        id: `data.${task.taskCreationDate}.sharedTask`,
        animation: 'move',
        resize: 'clip'
    }];
};
```